# XNA is not drawing what I tell it to

Tags: c#, xna, drawing, sprite, xna-4.0

I have this code that is supposed to draw two volume icons to the window, but it is not working. Here is the relevant code:

```
    Texture2D vol_max;
    Vector2 vol_max_vect;
    Texture2D vol_min;
    Vector2 vol_min_vect;
    ...
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        vol_max = Content.Load<Texture2D>("vol_max@16");
        vol_min = Content.Load<Texture2D>("vol_min@16");
    }
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        thisKeyboard = Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed ||
            thisKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        {
            this.Exit();
        }

        // Update window vectors
        vol_max_vect = new Vector2(
            (float)(Window.ClientBounds.Right - 20),
            (float)(Window.ClientBounds.Bottom - 20));
        vol_min_vect = new Vector2(
            (float)(Window.ClientBounds.Right - 140),
            (float)(Window.ClientBounds.Bottom - 20));

        prevKeyboard = thisKeyboard;

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(
            vol_max,
            vol_max_vect,
            Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(
            vol_min,
            vol_min_vect,
            Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the ClientBounds.Right/Bottom is in Windows screen coordinates (where [0,0] is the top left of your screen, and the bottom right is your resolution, eg. [1024, 768]).

What you really want is to draw them at the bottom right of your own window. XNA's SpriteBatch draws in viewport coordinates, where [0, 0] is the top left of your viewport, and the bottom right is your application's resolution eg. [800, 480]. To get that width, you can simply use Window.ClientBounds.Width instead of Window.ClientBounds.Right, and Window.ClientBounds.Height instead of Window.ClientBounds.Bottom.

Hopefully that helps!